# What does it mean for a logic symbol to have a fixed interpretation? (Tourlakis)

Tags: logic, soft-question, first-order-logic

In *Lectures in Logic and Set Theory, Volume 1* by George Tourlakis, the author is introducing first order languages, saying that there are some symbols common to every first order language. Then the author remarks, with a sign saying it is a important remark that "The logical symbols will have a fixed interpretation.". I don't understand what this is supposed to mean. I got this book because, i saw in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/155686) it being recommended for someone with a formalist view. I don't understand why the author would give this remark such importance, since it seems meaningless to me from a formalist perspective unless i'm missing something. Here are images of the book.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The truth of a first-order formula is evaluated relative to a structure consisting of a domain of objects and an interpretation function which gives meaning to the so-called non-logical symbols (= individual symbols like $zero$, function symbols like $plus$ and predicate symbols like $is{-}prime$). The interpretation of the latter will depend on the structure, whereas the meaning of the logical symbols is the same across all structures, which is why it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the "meaning" of the logical symbols does not change when we change the interpretation of the language, while the meaning of the non-logical ones: like e.g. $+$ for the language of arithmetic and $\in$ for the language of set theory, may change according to the interpretation.

See page 53, **Definition I.5.1**, for *structure appropriate for* a language $L$ and *interpretation*.

Example: the meaning of the logical connective "and" is exactly that defined by the [truth table for $\land$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

---

Regarding the "formalist" point of view, see again the introduction (page 3-on) with the discussion about *formalization* and “Formalism for the user”, that means:

> "to reason formally [instead of] to do so informally.
> The latter mode often mixes syntax and semantics (meaning), and there is always the danger that the “user” may assign incorrect (i.e., convenient, but not general ) meanings to the symbols that he manipulates."

The "meaning" we are discussing in the paragraph above is the "formal" meaning, defined by the mathematical semantics (structure, interpretation) and not the intuitive one.

Semantics assigns a reference to *terms* ("names") and truth value to formulas. Obviously, it is the mathematical counterpart in the framework of first-order logic of "meaning" for natural language expressions.

Comment: Then, "meaning" is just an intuitive thing?